# Does ServletContext.getRealPath() work with web fragments?

Tags: java, tomcat, war, servlet-3.0, getresource

I use web fragments (servlet 3 spec) and thus can load e.g. `META-INF/resources/access.xml` file which is in a library in `/WEB-INF/lib/` of my WAR via `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream("access.xml")`.

Doing the same with `ServletContext.getRealPath("access.xml")` doesn't work (=> `null`).

The spec states:

> The `getRealPath` method takes a `String` argument and returns a `String` representation of a file on the local file system to which a path corresponds. Resources inside the `META-INF/resources` directory of JAR file must be considered only if the container has unpacked them from their containing JAR file when a call to `getRealPath()`
>   is made, and in this case MUST return the unpacked location.

My container (Tomcat) didn't unpack the jars, this seems to be the problem? How can Tomcat unpack the jars. Should I unpack the jars when packaging the WAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `getResourcesAsStream()` always works. But `getRealPath()` doesn't.

Answer: Don't try to use `getRealPath()` together with web fragments.

Answer (score 0):

So it depends on what you are trying to do. If you are trying to get the location of the file in the included library dependency, then I am not sure. If you are wanting to read the contents of the `access.xml` file then you can use

```
new InputStreamReader(context.getResourcesAsStream("access.xml"));
```

and then work with the `InputStreamReader` to get the file's contents.